# A siri/google assistant capable video player please

Tags: android, ios

I need a video player that supports ok/hey X rewind x seconds. Also I need playlist support so I can say play x playlist. Vlc video cuts out after google assistant fast forwards and only audio plays. mx player doesn't support rewind or really playlists.